# Infinite loop when using a RemoteTestRunner with optimized unit test code

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, cil

**Some context first**: I'm working on a [mutation testing tool for C# + NUnit](https://github.com/criteo/NinjaTurtlesMutation), and for the sake of speed I'm
using an internal class of NUnit 2.6.4 Core assembly ([RemoteTestRunner](https://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/blob/master/src/NUnitCore/core/RemoteTestRunner.cs)) to [run tests](https://github.com/criteo/NinjaTurtlesMutation/blob/master/NinjaTurtlesMutation/ManagedTestRunners/NUnitManagedTestRunner.cs) (see the `DoTests` method at the bottom) in a separate AppDomain.

**The problem**:
I have a unit test that poll a variable until it become non null. This variable is a Dictionary assign as null, and then reassign to a real dictionary by an Action triggered by a Timer. When building the test assembly with code optimization, it never end. The problematic code:

```
[Test]
public void WeirdOne()
{
    using (var accumulator = new Accumulator<string>(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)))
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> pack = null;
        accumulator.NewPack += p => pack = p;
        accumulator.Add("D");
        accumulator.Add("A");
        accumulator.Add("M");
        accumulator.Add("N");

        while (pack == null) ;

        Assert.That(pack.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));
    }
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/TonyRoussel/45bc1c4ec4a3a7c236ae6e542db107e7) a gist with the Accumulator implem if needed.

**What I have found**:

- If I put something inside the `while` loop (tested with a `Thread.Sleep` and a `WriteLine`), then I have no more problem running the test to the end
- If I trigger the `NewPack` Action from the `Accumulator.Add` method, the test goes to the end
- Just to ensure the Timer effectively do its job, I tried to add a `File.Create()` just before calling the `NewPack` Action. The file was created, with or without code optimization
- No problem when launch with nunit-console (2.6.2 / 2.6.4), with or without optimization

Since NUnit can launch this and go to the end, I suspect that I'm missing something when instantiating all the RemoteTestRunnner's environment.

Does anyone encounter this kind debug/release build issue ? Any lead about what I'm missing ?

Thanks for reading !

**Edit**: As pointed by Aleksey L.

> define this variable as instance field and mark it as volatile

avoid the infinite loop, but still no hint about how nunit-console work that out

Answer (score 2):

Maybe processor is caching `pack` value as `null`. Try to define this variable as instance field and mark it as `volatile` (to be on the safe side). Though this doesn't explain why *No problem when launch with nunit-console (2.6.2 / 2.6.4), with or without optimization*